Flutter _TypeError in FutureBuilder when Navigating After Token Validation
I've been working on a Flutter app where I'm trying to implement login persistence across the app. The idea is that once the user logs in, their session should persist until the token expires, even if they close and reopen the app. I'm storing the JWT token securely and checking its validity on app launch.
The problem:
After validating the token, I'm facing a _TypeError: Null check operator used on a null value in the _onGenerateRoute method in app.dart (a part of Flutter's core widgets).
What I'm doing:
Using a FutureBuilder to decide the initial route based on the token's validity.
Navigating to the home screen if the token is valid, or to the login screen if not.
Here is the relevant code from main.dart:
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late Future<bool> isUserLoggedIn;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    isUserLoggedIn = checkUserLoggedIn();
  }

  Future<bool> checkUserLoggedIn() async {
    try {
      final userService = userservice();
      final isValid = await userService.isTokenValid();
      print('Token validity check completed: $isValid');
      return isValid;
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error checking token validity: $e');
      return false; // Return false in case of any error
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<bool>(
      future: isUserLoggedIn,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        print('FutureBuilder: ConnectionState = ${snapshot.connectionState}');
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          print('Loading indicator shown while waiting for Future result.');
          return MaterialApp(
            home: Scaffold(
              body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
            ),
          );
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          bool userLoggedIn = snapshot.data ?? false; // Ensure non-null value
          print('FutureBuilder: ConnectionState = ConnectionState.done');
          print('User logged in: $userLoggedIn');

          return MaterialApp(
            title: 'POS App',
            initialRoute: userLoggedIn ? AppRoutes.Home : '/',
            routes: {
              '/': (context) => loginPage(),
              AppRoutes.SignUp: (context) => SignUp(),
              AppRoutes.Home: (context) => home(),
            },
          );
        }

        // Fallback in case of unexpected state
        return MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: Text('Unexpected error. Please restart the app.'),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

What I've Tried:
Added print statements for debugging. It shows that the token validation check completes and returns false, leading to navigation to the login page.
Checked if the snapshot has data before using it.
Used a fallback route in case of unexpected states.
Despite these attempts, the error persists after navigating post token validation.
Question:
What could be causing this error in the context of navigating after token validation? Is there a best practice for handling navigation using FutureBuilder that might help prevent this _TypeError? Any insights into handling routes more safely in Flutter, especially after asynchronous checks, would be appreciated.
Can anyone help?
Thanks In Advance :)

I don't see a null check operator in the given code, can you post the detailed Stack Trace? And then we can find the exact place where the exception occurs?
